# Самоочевидное и просто очевидное

Tags: значение-слов, словообразование, смысл

Примеры не столько для обсуждения, сколько для иллюстрации. Хотя вопрос может быть и конкретным тоже: что-то изменится, поменяй мы «самочевидное» на «очевидное»?

> Неизвестное, как условие всякого вопроса, само, таким образом,
> предельно бесспорно, самоочевидно, «безвопросно» в буквальном и
> абсолютном смысле этого слова. [С. Л. Франк. Непостижимое (1938)]
>
> Наверное, нет. Это самоочевидно. Другой практически неизбежный
> ускоритель старения книг ― это пыль. [Г. Рожкова. Враги книги и как с
> ними бороться // «Химия и жизнь», 1967]
>
> То, что моим способом самовыражения станет кинематограф, было вполне
> самоочевидно. [О. В. Аронсон. Коммуникативный образ. Кино. Литература.
> Философия. Ч. II (2007)]

Answer (score 1):

Викисловарь отмечает широкий диапазон значений слова «очевидно»: от констатации факта «несомненно, бесспорно, ясно», - к выражению «неуверенного подтверждения», и далее к предположениям и домыслам, сближаясь по смыслу с «возможно, вероятно, по-видимому».

А он, очевидно догадываясь, что произошло что-то необычайное, торопливо спрашивал: — Я сквозь сон слышал стрельбу. Почему же замолчали наши орудия? Почему нет грохота от неприятельских снарядов? А. С. Новиков-Прибой, «Цусима», 1932–1935 г.(НКРЯ).

Такая многозначность слова, вынудила использовать для варианта «очевидно = несомненно» дополнительное определение «самый (что ни на есть)». Этому есть примеры в нацкорпусе:

Но когда всмотришься в нее, то находишь в ней столько истинной житейской теплоты, столько действительной любви, активной, а не фразерской, что опирайся смело на руку такого человека на самом краю пропасти, и тебе стоять весело рядом даже с самой очевидной опасностью. [Н. В. Шелгунов. Люди сороковых и шестидесятых годов (1867) // «Дело», 1869] (НКРЯ).
― В том, ― продолжал я, ― что вы в этом деле невинны и не способны ни на что подобное, я убежден,  как в самой очевидной аксиоме,  и никакие вещественные доказательства не могут переубедить меня. [А. А. Шкляревский. Что побудило к убийству? (Рассказы следователя) (1879)] (НКРЯ).
Это только смелое и голословное утверждение самой очевидной неправды, которая разрушается при первой серьезной мысли об этом. [Л. Н. Толстой. В чем моя вера? (1884)] (НКРЯ).
По крайней мере, я это вижу с ясностью, которой яснее не может быть самая очевидная вещь. [Н. С. Лесков. Письма Л. Н. Толстому (1887-1894)] (НКРЯ).

Вероятно, со временем, «самое (что ни на есть) очевидное» сократилось до «самоочевидное», например:
Этот путь есть абсолютное благо и, во всяком случае, самоочевидное наименьшее зло. [Н. Н. Суханов. Записки о революции / Книга 1 (1918-1921)] (НКРЯ).

И так, если словом "очевидно" выражено сомнение (возможно, вероятно, по-видимому), то его замена на "самоочевидно" будет неуместной.

Comment: Из второго примера «Наверное, нет. Это самоочевидно» — неуместно? Не лишним будет сказать, что конструкция эта — с *само-*, первой частью сложных прилагательных, является разговорной. *Самый* (качеств. превосх.), — **склоняемое** прилагательное. Сокращенние до неизменяемого *само-* приводит к потере очень важного свойства. Возможно, потому и снижена до статуса небезупречной такая конструкция.